# rotating y-axis to top and x-axis to left within chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I have a chart that's currently displaying like:

[image]

But I'd like to rotate it to look more like this:
[image]

(not changing the "your rating") orientation.

It should be relatively straightforward to put the x-axis on the left and the y-axis on the top, but I'm struggling.

Here is the relevant code:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
window.myHorizontalBar = new Chart(ctx, {
  type:'line',    // 'horizontalBar',
  data: horizontalBarChartData,
  options: {
    annotation: {
         annotations: [{
           type: 'line',
       mode: 'vertical',
       scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
       value: 20,
       label: {
         content: 'Your Rating   ',
         enabled: true
           }
         }]
       },
scales: {
    xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
            display:false
        }
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      gridLines: {
            display:false
        }
    }]
},

    // Elements options apply to all of the options unless overridden in a dataset
    // In this case, we are setting the border of each horizontal bar to be 2px wide

    responsive: true,
    legend: {

       display: false
    },
    title: {
      display: false,
      text: 'text4'
    }
  }
});
```

}

Comment: A relatively simple hack if it doesn't work out may be to use css to transform the chart rotate(90deg) and rotate the tooltip-container class rotate(-90deg) so that it would be straight